# what is 'field_ft_' in the parameter for expression engine save_entry() function

Tags: php, expressionengine

I'm looking at the documentation for expression engine save_entry function and am trying to understand the possible parameters. What is 'field_ft_ ' and what are the possible values?

from the doc:

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

$data = array(
    'title'         => 'Breaking News Story!',
    'entry_date'    => '1256953732',
    'edit_date'     => '1351653729',
    'field_id_6'    => 'Some data',
    'field_ft_6'    => 'none',
    'field_id_19'   => 'More data',
    'field_ft_19'   => 'xhtml'
);

ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);

$success = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $channel_id);

    if ( ! $success)
    {
            show_error(implode('<br />', $this->api_channel_entries->errors));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a field in Expression Engine you assign it a default "field type".

Under some circumstances individual entries can use a field type other than the default one.

There are a number of field types built in to expression engine and additional field types can be added by add-ons.

There's a table `exp_fieldtypes` that lists field types. I don't see xhtml or none there, which are built in to EE.  Maybe the default ones are not included?  Perhaps some one can improve this answer.